# OpenCV Memory Usage Issue with huge images

Tags: opencv, memory, tiff, imshow, imread

I realized a memory usage issue when I try to display huge images such as a 2GB of TIFF image. 
The code is below:

```
Mat image, output;

image = imread("img.tif", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
//Memory usage : 2GB

normalize(image, output, 0, 0xFFFF, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
//Memory usage : 4GB

namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("Display Image", output);
//Memory usage : 6.5GB

waitKey(0);
```

When I run this program step-by-step in Debug mode on Ubuntu environment, I saw that memory usage is increasing tremendously from System Monitor.

When **imread** is hit, my program uses approximately **2GB** of memory.
When **normalize** is called, it increases to approximately **4GB**.
And finally when **imshow** is called, it increases to **~6.5GB**.

So what i think it creates new copies everytime I call imread, normalize and imshow.

Is there any way to overcome this issue ?
What I think is that maybe i can manually normalize my original image, but is it possible to use imshow with reference of my original Mat object instead of creating a new one ?

Comment: Since your .tif file is 2GB, I am wondering if your .tif image is a single image or contains multiple images (image sequence)?

Comment: "When normalize is called, it increases to approximately 4GB." -- you did tell it to store the result in a second variable... | `imshow` uses an internal buffer to store the image in a format it can render. It's also a rudimentary convenience function. If you need a smarter UI, you most likely need to write your own.

Comment: @Ali it is one plain image which is constrcuted by stiching several images side-by-side.

Comment: @Dan Mašek I understand the case so i think i can conclude that i'm not doing something pointless, but the internal mechanics of opencv works that way. I am now wondering if there is any alternative solution for me to basically display a huge tif image on screen without consuming too much memory ?

Comment: Yeah, such large images are quite a corner case. How exactly do you want to display it -- based on the amount of data, I assume at original scale it is much too large to fit all on a single screen, correct? Do you want to display it scaled down (that's simple, just scale it down prior to calling `imshow`)? Or do you want to show it at original scale and be able to scroll around (that will take some work).

Comment: It is actually a panchromatic image taken from a satellite and the pixel size is roughly 36000x32000 which is of course not possible to fit into the screen. Since this is a satellite image, there will be necessity to zoom in or zoom out which means i don't want to lose any resolution (compression is not an option in that case)

Comment: You might consider looking at `libvips` and DeepZoom https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996099/2836621

Comment: Also https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.md.html